# How to retrieve only updated records based on `updated_at` column in Active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to retrieve all the records from table which are updated. 
Here i am considering updation of only `updated_at` column and no other column.

As whenever a new record is created, both `created_at and updated_at` columns have same timestamp, so i want to get all the records whose `updated_at` column has changed from the initial assignment.

My query:

`@obj = User.where(:receiver_id => current_user.id).where("updated_at - created_at > ?",0).order('created_at DESC')`. and getting 'PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval > integer'.

My another big question is, Is it valid to find the difference between two columns of the table in single query ?

Please suggest if any good way of doing it other than above method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it simpler:

```
@obj = User.where(:receiver_id => current_user.id).where('updated_at != created_at').order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: nice, it works with your code but when trying with `where('updated_at == created_at')` and it shows `PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone == timestamp without time zone`

Comment: @Rahul `==` doesn't exist in SQL, use `=`

Comment: SQL does not use `=` for assignment, only for comparison. So, there is no valid syntax for `==`, only for `=`.